# Does VS 2015 Azure Publish wizard not deal with ARM created resources?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-resource-manager

I can see ARM Cloud Services from the Publish wizard but do not see ARM storage when using an admin account. I am able to Publish to ARM Cloud service with admin account but must specify ASM storage account.

When using an account with RBAC access limited to a resource group that contains the above cloud service, the publish wizard says cloud services are not available in this subscription. VS Cloud Explore shows the correct RBAC limited resources except of the Cloud Service. I can log in to the crappy new portal with the RBAC limited account and I see the expected cloud service and supporting resources.

Anybody having success Publishing with RBAC limited accounts from within Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Cloud Service Publish Wizard in Visual Studio currently only speaks to the Azure Service Management APIs.  So anything that requires going through the Azure Resource Manager APIs (V2 Storage, RBAC'd accounts/subscriptions) won't show up in the publish wizard.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quickly tiring of having to figure out that the tooling doesn't keep up with tools.