# Why can't authorized user publish azure cloud service worker role app to azure cloud service container?

Tags: permissions, azure-cloud-services

I have a single MSDN subscription (with $150 per month credit on Azure). I am experimenting with cloud service worker role app in Azure. I have 2 user accounts (say A for Admin and B for Developer) with Azure. I provisioned a cloud app as user A and gave rights to user B with Owner and Contributor roles. I logged into Azure as user B and can see clearly see this cloud service empty container. Next, as user B (developer), I authored a cloud service with worker role (using VS 2015 enterprise) and tested on my personal machine. When I try to publish this app to azure after logging in as user B (through visual studio), the Publish Azure Application dialog box shows my MSDN subscription. Once I select the subscription, it shows a red x mark next to the subscription. When I hovered over the red x mark, it says "Cloud Serivces are not available in this subscription.". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like my question is answered in the following post: [does-vs-2015-azure-publish-wizard-not-deal-with-arm-created-resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485594/does-vs-2015-azure-publish-wizard-not-deal-with-arm-created-resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had both VS 2013 as well as VS 2015 installed on my machine. However I had installed Azure SDK 2.8 for VS 2015 only. With this setup, I was not able to publish the cloud service to azure. Today I installed the same SDK for VS 2013 as well. All of a sudden I can publish and view my cloud services through server explorer in both VS 2013 as well as VS 2015. Go figure!